# Why can't I perform Ajax get on this website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Seeking to bypass the Same-Origin Policy (and absent a backend server -- I only have a website and it's JS script hosted on Google Drive) I decided to use [WhateverOrigin](https://whateverorigin.herokuapp.com/) for the project I'm working on for someone.

Until now it's worked on every website -- except for [this one](http://afcl.ussoccerda.com/sam/teams/index.php?team=1642601) where it returns a 404.

See [my JSFiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/tos6522z/1/) (or code snippet below) for comparison between the not-working page, and a working one (for some reason the functions are working in reverse order or something, but commenting out one of the function calls shows clearly which URL is working and which isn't).

```js
// for some reason this is calling the functions in the reverse order -- but try commenting out and you'll see that the second one doesn't work, the first one does

$(function() {

  works();
  notWorking();

  function works() {
    $.getJSON('https://whateverorigin.herokuapp.com/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent("http://afcl.ussoccerda.com/sam/teams/index.php") + '&callback=?', function(data) {
      alert(data.contents);
    });
  }

  function notWorking() {
    $.getJSON('https://whateverorigin.herokuapp.com/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent("http://afcl.ussoccerda.com/sam/teams/index.php?team=1642601") + '&callback=?', function(data) {
      alert(data.contents);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hurl.it is able to get the page data for it just fine though:
[image]

I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong programmatically, or how I can fix this otherwise. I don't have too many options beyond using WhateverOrigin at this point, since my entire project is based on it, and everything else is working except for this one webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that in the final version the web application and the server will be on the same domain and you just need to do cross origin requests during development. 
If you only need to do cross origin requests in development, then use chrome for your development and install the "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" plugin for chrome and enable cross origin access.

Comment: In the final version the web application & the server won't be on the same domain -- it'll be the way I have it now, and the person I'm doing this script/website for (can't get anymore specific than that) will have to be able to use it. Every URL on that US Soccer Development Academy has worked, except for the [specific one](http://afcl.ussoccerda.com/sam/teams/index.php?team=1642601) I referenced. I don't get why only that one is failing with my code.

Comment: Try using jsonp, instead of ajax

Comment: doesn't the site I request HTML info from need to have Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set to allow cross-domain requests, if I use JSONP? Currently, with WhateverOrigin I can bypass that restriction.

Comment: I was about to mention that. Can you edit the server to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set to allow cross-domain requests?

Comment: I cannot, unfortunately.

Comment: You could try using a proxy such as the one described here.